# Ticket between 2 zones : edited

Tags: deutsche-bahn

If I have a monthly pass of 1 zone(city) and I want to go to another zone(city2) 2, can I just buy a day ticket of zone 2 and travel from zone 1 to zone 2 ?

Its about cities.

Wolfsburg and Braunschweig
Having a monatskarte of one of them and want to go to the other via regio Bahn

Comment: Because of the deutsche bahn tag I assume your question is about Germany. But about which city?

Comment: Since you mention zones, I assume this is about some transport association rather than Deutsche Bahn...Therefore, please name both cities and both zone numbers (are they really called 1 and 2?), as some networks are set up in such a way that what's true between A and B (zone 1 and 2) is not true between A and C (zone 1 and 3) or similar things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accroding to [price table](https://www.vrb-online.de/fileadmin/pdf/Preisstufentabelle_ab_1.1.2019.pdf) it's price zone 3 from Wolfsburg to Braunschweig, not 2.
So you will need a ticket for price zone 3 ([prices](https://www.vrb-online.de/index.php?id=160&start=40&ziel=20&submit=Suchen)).

However, if you have a month ticket, you can buy an [Erweiterungskarte](https://www.vrb-online.de/index.php?id=289) (extension ticket) which allows you to travel across the whole VRB area for 2,50€ (one-way).

Comment: Just to confirm if I understood this correctly. So with and extension ticket, I can go to Wolfsburg (I have a Plus-Monatskart for Braunschweig). Right ? Sorry for repeating but the translation is a little typical and I don't want to end up in a wrong situation.

Comment: Yes, this is what is said in the linked page. You can ask at a counter at the train station whether it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Wolfsburg is zone 20, Braunschweig is Zone 40, https://www.wvg.de/fileadmin/wvg/files/PDF2016/Tarifzonen.PDF

The zones do not touch, but you'd have to go through either zone 16 or 36. In this case you would need a 3-zone ticket or "Price Level 3" per this info. https://www.wvg.de/fileadmin/user_upload/VRB-Flyer_Need-help_DE-EN-FR_2019_03-19_WEB.pdf

If you can read German, this is a better link https://www.wvg.de/fahrgastinfo/tickets-preise.html

Most of the trains seem to operated by Enno https://www.der-enno.de/fahrkarten/gvh-und-vrb/ so if you buy a VRB ticket you can take these trains. You probably can not take a train operated by Deutsche Bundesbahn with a VRB ticket and would need a seperate tickets. Given the short distance, the bahn high speed trains really don't offer and advantage anyway.